# swift array Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject' to expected argument type @noescape(AnyObject) throws - > Bool

Tags: swift

```
    let otherArray:[AnyObject] = ["a","aa","aaa"]
    let otherArrayElemnt = otherArray[0]
    let myArray:[AnyObject] = ["qq"]
    if myArray.contains(otherArrayElemnt){     //<<<<<<< Error HERE
        //if contains...doSomething
    }else{
        //none doSomething
    }
```

Error: Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject' to expected argument type @noscape (AnyObject) throws -> Bool

I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

1. `String` is not an object, so it does not conform to protocol `AnyObject`. Use `Any` instead.
2. Neither `AnyObject` nor `Any` is `Equatable`, so function `contains` doesn't know how to compare elements of the array with `otherArrayElement`.

Why do you need to use arrays of `Any` elements ? Why don't you use arrays of `String`s ? What else do you want to store in them ?